# I can use `AND` in place of `WHERE` in MySQL queries, is this a bug or a feature

Tags: mysql

I have found in MySQL when doing joins, I can use the word `AND` in place of `WHERE` like so:

```
SELECT * FROM `mySchema`.`tblOne`
LEFT JOIN `mySchema`.`tblTwo` ON `tblOne`.`FIELDX` = `tblTwo`.`FIELDY`
AND `FIELDZ` = 'FooBar';
```

Is this a bug or is there a feature? Are there scenarios where this could be useful?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that using `ON ... AND ...` can give different results from `ON ... WHERE`:

```
SELECT * FROM `mySchema`.`tblOne` 
LEFT JOIN `mySchema`.`tblTwo` ON `tblOne`.`FIELDX` = `tblTwo`.`FIELDY` 
AND `FIELDZ` = 'FooBar';
```

If FIELDZ is in tblTwo (not clear from the above), this will return **all** rows from `tblOne`, and join matching rows from tblTwo (i.e. those which have FIELDY = tblOne.FIELDX and FIELDZ = 'FooBar')

```
SELECT * FROM `mySchema`.`tblOne` 
LEFT JOIN `mySchema`.`tblTwo` ON `tblOne`.`FIELDX` = `tblTwo`.`FIELDY` 
WHERE `FIELDZ` = 'FooBar';
```

If FIELDZ is in tblTwo, this will join on `tblOne`.`FIELDX` = `tblTwo`.`FIELDY`, then filter by`tblTwo.FIELDY = 'FooBar'.  It will effectively be the same as an INNER JOIN.

Answer (score 4):

your `AND` is for the `ON` clause, this doesn't have to do with a `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 3):

If you take a look at the documentation for `JOIN` ([link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)), you will see, that after the `ON` keyword there is a `conditional_expr`.

This is the same `conditional_expr` as used in `WHERE` clauses. So basically you are able to do the same stuff after an `ON` like after a `WHERE`.

Following that, you are also able to use `AND` and `OR`, parenthesis and all other conditional operators there.

Answer (score 0):

This works in SQL Server 2008 as well. I don't see how it would be a bug. The 'ON' portion of the JOIN is similar to a 'WHERE'. Basically what your query says is:

```
WHERE tblOne.FIELDX = tblTwo.FIELDY AND FIELDZ = 'FooBar';
```

You could use:

```
ON FIELDX = FIELDY AND FIELDZ = 'FooBar'
```

or:

```
ON FIELDX = FIELDY
WHERE FIELDZ = 'FooBar'
```